# Adding an invisible document name in XSLT or HTML

Tags: html, xml, xslt

I have this XSLT document that has a file name. However for archiving purposes we want the file name to be displayed somewhere else within the code.

Now I used to do this like this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    sample-xml=".\DOCUMENTNAME.xml"
    xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml"
    xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office">
```

However we want to get rid of this solution due to new working methods. Now I was wondering if I could place this (literally just the word DOCUMENTNAME) somewhere within the XSL or within the HTML wrapped within it, in a way that it is not visible.

We add this code to a database, through a validator that looks for the documentname and checks for a match. And as only the contents of the code is placed on the database its easier to check back from the database what documentname was uploaded. However this documentname should not be visible in an HTML output.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe add a processing instruction or comment somewhere in the XSLT.

Like:

```
<?DOCUMENTNAME?>
```

or:

```
<!--DOCUMENTNAME-->
```

They're not invisible, but they definitely won't be included in the output.

Answer (score 0):

Not visible to whom?

Your current solution (with sample-xml) is not valid XSLT: unknown attributes on an XSLT element should be rejected by the processor unless they are in a namespace of their own.

The cleanest way to do this is probably a top-level element (a child of `xsl:stylesheet`) in a private namespace:

```
<my:document-name xmlns:my="http://my.company.com/ns/document-id">document.xml</my:document-name>
```

I don't know if that meets your criteria of being "not visible". It certainly wouldn't be visible in the output of the stylesheet.